# Swift OSX Change color of NSMenuItem Title

Tags: swift, nsmenuitem

How do I add a label to NSMenuItem that is disabled but not greyed out.

`let addToComputerItem : NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "\(title)", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
        computerInfoMenu.addItem(addToComputerItem)
        addToComputerItem.enabled = false`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let menu = NSMenuItem(title: "Test", action: #selector(AppDelegate.test), keyEquivalent: "K")

menu.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Testinggg", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: NSFont.systemFontOfSize(20), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.redColor()])

mainMenu?.itemAtIndex(0)?.submenu?.addItem(menu)//You can add whichever submenu
```

Comment: This adds an "empty" menu bar item.

Comment: Updated my answer, it should work. Please let me know.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I got error at (AppDelegate.test) : `Use of unresolved identifier 'AppDelegate'`. Please help